# When is $-1$ in the image of a field norm?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory

Let $p >0$ be an odd prime and let $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta) \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ with $\zeta$ a primitive $p$th root of unity. There is a unique subfield $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{F} \subseteq \mathbb{K}$ satisfying $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}]=2$. Specifically $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha^2 = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}p$.

If $p \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ then $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}] = (p-1)/2$ is odd so $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}(-1) = (-1)^{[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{F}]} = -1$, where $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}} : \mathbb{K} \to \mathbb{F}$ is the field norm.

> When $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ why is $-1$ not in the image of $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}$?

This should be very elementary and for reasons coming from representation theory of finite groups I know this statement is true. However I'd like a straightforward number theory argument for this.

My basic idea was the following. We have $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}] = p-1$ and by assumption $4 \mid p-1$ so there exists a unique subfield $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq\mathbb{E} \subseteq \mathbb{K}$ with $[\mathbb{E}:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. By transitivity of norms, if $-1$ is in the image of $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}$ then it's also in the image of $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{E/F}}$. Hence, it suffices to show it's not in the image of $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{E/F}}$. Here is where I got a bit stuck as I wasn't sure what the field $\mathbb{E}$ is exactly. One can get a basis by taking Galois sums of $\zeta$. There might also be a way to use the discriminent.

I have the same question in the local case. So assume $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}(\zeta)$ with $\ell > 0$ a prime and $\zeta \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$ a primitive $p$th root of unity. Looking in Serre's Local Fields the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ should still be cyclic. So assume $2$ divides $[\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}]$ then there is a unique subfield $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}\subseteq\mathbb{F} \subseteq \mathbb{K}$ with $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}]=2$. The following should be true:

> If $\ell \neq p$ then $-1$ is in the image of the norm map $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}$. If $\ell = p$ then $-1$ is in the image of the norm map $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}$ if and only if $p \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$.

By a block theory argument from finite groups I know the statement when $\ell \neq p$ is true. Hasse's Norm Theorem would then imply that the $\ell = p$ case agrees with the global case. However this all feels far too overblown. There should be an elementary number theory argument for all of this.

Apologies in advance if this is all too elementary. I am sure these answers and arguments are well known.

Comment: In your last highlighted item, you are saying in part that for a prime $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, $-1$ is not a norm from $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)$ down to $\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt{p})$. But this extension has degree $(p-1)/2$, and if $\omega$ is a $(p-1)$th root of unity in $\mathbf Q_p$ then its norm for the field extension $\mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)/\mathbf Q_p(\sqrt{p})$ is $\omega^{(p-1)/2}$, which is $\pm 1$ and is $-1$ for half the choices of $\omega$.

Comment: My previous argument has nothing to do with $p$ being $1 \bmod 4$. For an odd prime $p$, the field $K = \mathbf Q_p(\zeta_p)$ has cyclic Galois group $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$ over $\mathbf Q_p$, so $K$ contains a quadratic subfield $F/\mathbf Q_p$ inside $K$. If $\omega$ is a $(p-1)$th root of unity in $\mathbf Q_p$ then ${\rm N}_{K/F}(\omega) = \omega^{(p-1)/2}$, which is $1$ for half the choices of $\omega$ and $-1$ for the other half. In particular, $-1 \in {\rm N}_{K/F}(K^\times)$ for all odd $p$.

Comment: Let $a = p+b\sqrt{p}$, where $b$ is an even, positive integer such that $b^2+c^2=p$ for some integer $c$. The subfield $\mathbb{E}$ must be $\mathbb{F}(\sqrt{\pm a })$, where the sign is $+$ if $4 \mid b$ and $-$ otherwise. See page 2 of  http://www.pphmj.com/abstract/1486.htm .Your conclusion is simple enough in the case $4 \nmid b$, but the case $4 \mid b$ seems harder to me.

Comment: Maybe I've overlooked something here, but: if $p = 1 \bmod 4$, isn't $\mathbb{F}$ totally real and $\mathbb{K}$ totally complex, and so any norm from $\mathbb{K}$ to $\mathbb{F}$ has to totally positive and thus can't be $-1$?

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that the OP is using the exact same notation for a cyclotomic and quadratic extension of $\mathbf Q$ as for a cyclotomic and quadratic extension of a local field, which makes it a bit confusing to keep straight which norm mapping is being discussed.  A rational number may be in the image of the norm mapping for the local field extension without being in the image of the mapping for the number field extension.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Ah, thanks, I was hoping to get some argument like that by passing to the smaller extension $\mathbb{E}$, so as to mimic the situation with $\mathbb{R}(\zeta)/\mathbb{R}$. I see now if you take $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1}) \subseteq \mathbb{K}$ to be the maximal real subfield then for any $x \in \mathbb{E}$ you have $\mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{K/F}}(x) = \mathrm{N}_{\mathbb{E/F}}(x)^2$ so it will be positive.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks for pointing that out about the $\ell = p$ case. I had mostly been thinking of the $\ell \neq p$ case where, of course, it might happen that $\zeta \in \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ when $p \mid \ell -1$. That's not quite what I was expecting in the $\ell = p$ case. Perhaps I've not translated my question from rep theory correctly in the $\ell$-adic case.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky Thanks for the reference giving a description of $\mathbb{E}$. I was curious what that field would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Global question*: If $p = 1 \bmod 4$, then the element $-1 \in F^\times$ is not a norm from $K^\times$, because $F^\times$ is totally real and $K^\times$ is totally complex; thus $-1$ is not a local norm at either of the infinite places of $F$, and hence cannot be a global norm either.

*Local question, $\ell \ne p$*: If $\ell \ne p$ then the fields $K$ and $F$ you define are both unramified extensions of $\mathbf{Q}_\ell$. Hence $N_{K/F}(O_K^\times) = O_F^\times$, and in particular contains $-1$. (This surjectivity result for the norm map on units follows from the analogous result for the residue fields, which is easy to prove by hand, see slide 6 of [these lecture notes by Garrett](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/number_theory/overheads/noth-04-09-2012.pdf).)

*Local question, $\ell = p$*: As pointed out by KConrad in the comments, if you take $\omega$ a $(p-1)$-st root of unity in $\mathbf{Q}_p^\times \subseteq F^\times$, then the composite $F^\times \hookrightarrow K^\times \xrightarrow{N_{K/F}} F^\times$ is raising to the $(p-1)/2$-th power; so its image contains $\omega^{(p-1)/2}$ for every $(p-1)$-st root of unity, i.e. it always contains $-1$.

(You were correct in deducing from Hasse's theorem that if $-1$ is not a norm globally then it had to fail to be a norm locally at some place. However, the bad place is not $p$ but $\infty$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Somehow I was not paying attention to the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ had two real primes. The argument for the $\ell \neq p$ case is also pleasingly close to the block theory argument.